# HttpURLConnection responseCode 405 method not allowed error

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, ioexception, http-status-code-405

We are trying to send request an integration web api from an external provider. They are using IP authorization and our IP is defined on their integration system.

We are having 405 error when create HttpUrlConnection and we can't send request this URL. When we try create HttpUrlConnection with main domain "http://api.relateddigital.com" having 403 error.

The provider firm is saying "We haven't any constraint for your IP addresses. The error is associated with your network."
How can we solve it?

Our Code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final URL url=new URL("http://api.relateddigital.com/resta/api/auth/login");
        final HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("connection.getResponseCode() :: "  + connection.getResponseCode());
        //the output is 405
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: connect in progress at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(Unknown Source)
    }

}
```

Comment: You are calling a login API but you set POST method after getting response code, and you are not specifying your credentials at all, many things are wrong before we can even start looking deeper for you.

Comment: I'm not sure if that may help you. I executed a similar code in Android, but it failed with the same error on every other site. They may not have anything against your IP, but they may have a requirement to provide the type of browser you are using (or something). To cut it short, I've no idea what it does, but 405 was resolved by adding connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0 Safari/537.36"); in my case.

Comment: Hi Eugene,
When I try setRequestProperty with the value I get from https://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ I am getting this error:
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(Unknown Source).

It couldn't solve.

Comment: Hi Chor,
Many sites using HttpUrlConnection like my example.

https://www.journaldev.com/7148/java-httpurlconnection-example-java-http-request-get-post and 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

They are setting POST after connection success

Comment: hmm look at his code line by line, con.getResponseCode() is after setting POST..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it thanks to @Chor Wai Chun.

I had overlook that getResponseCode() must be after the connection params.

Thanks everyone!

It worked with like this:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://api.relateddigital.com/resta/api/Datawarehouse/InsertUpdateRowInDwTable");
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
...
...
...
if ((connection.getResponseCode() < 200) || (connection.getResponseCode() >= 300))
        {
            final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(inputLine);
            }

            System.out.println("Error builder::" + builder);
            in.close();
            return;
        }
```